# How to get WebGrid column names dynamically

Tags: asp.net, webgrid, dynamic-columns

I have a table which will have a few fixed columns and then a lot of dynamic ones depending upon how the pivot results.

So this works just fine:

```
@{

    var db = Database.Open("STUDENT");
    var TeacherID = 15313;

    var selectCommand = "PBIS_ReviewBehaviors  @0, @1"; 

    var selectedData0 = db.Query(selectCommand, TeacherID, 0);
    var grid0 = new WebGrid(source: selectedData0, rowsPerPage: 30); 

    List<WebGridColumn> cols0 = new List<WebGridColumn>();

}
```

and then the body:

```
<div>
    @grid0.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt"// ,
     //   columns: cols
    )
</div>
```

however I really want to be able to do some spcific things with some of my fixed columns -  in order to do that i need to know who to get the column names in Data0 or Grid0 so then I can build up a list called cols and use it:

something like

```
foreach (column name in my grid)
{
    if column name = "StudentID"

cols0.Add(grid0.column(    format: @<a href="~/InsertStudent?StudentID=@item.StudentID">Details</a>   );

else

cols0.Add(grid0.column( the column name );

}
```

Alas I am very new to .net and do not know how I get my list of column names and then use them specifically.    I have hopefully made the pseudocode clear enough with my intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the columns returned by the database query via the [GetDynamicMemberNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicmetaobject.getdynamicmembernames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
foreach(var item in selectedData0.First().GetDynamicMemberNames()){
    // assumes that the query will always return at least one row
    // will throw an exception if not
    // 'item' represents the column name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you !

the workable solution was:

```
try 
{    
    foreach(var i in selectedData0.First().GetDynamicMemberNames() ) 
    {
        if(i == "StudentID") {
            cols0.Add(grid0.Column(format: @<a href="~/DetailStudent?StudentID=@item.StudentID">Details</a>) );
        }
        else {
            cols0.Add(grid0.Column(i.ToString())  );
        }
    }
}
catch {}
```

This replaced my first column with a link to another page and kept the rest dynamic to what was returned.    Because it  possible to have no rows returned I put in the try / catch.

Comment: Instead of the `try - catch`, you could test for null: `if(selectedData0.FirstOrDefault() != null)...`